# How to enable SystemChrome - SystemUiOverlayStyle in Flutter

Tags: flutter

please I tried to set SystemChrome.setSystemUiOverlayStyle() based on a condition that is bool value stored in phone using shared_preferences. Even if dark mode is true or not, SystemChrome.setSystemUiOverlayStyle did not work or changed on the condition when app launched. Sorry my bad English grammar. Below is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:kjv_bible/screens/book_chapters.dart';
import 'package:kjv_bible/screens/home_page.dart';
import 'package:kjv_bible/utils/color_helper.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'providers/setting_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'models/theme_preferences.dart';

void main() => runApp(Bible());

class Bible extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BibleState createState() => _BibleState();
}

class _BibleState extends State<Bible> {
  SharedPreferences _prefs;
  bool _isDark;

  @override
  void initState() {
    setTheme();
    super.initState();
  }

  void setTheme() async {
    _isDark = false;
    if (_prefs == null) _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    if (_prefs.containsKey('theme')) {
      _isDark = _prefs.getBool('theme') == true ? true : false;
    } else {
      _isDark = false;
    }

    if (_isDark) {
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: color("#232D36"),
        statusBarColor: color("#101D25"),
      ));
    } else {
      SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
        systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.white,
        statusBarColor: color("#22A2EE"),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(value: SettingProvider()),
      ],
      child: Consumer<SettingProvider>(builder: (ctx, status, _) {
        return MaterialApp(
          theme: status.darkTheme ? darkTheme : lightTheme,
          title: "Bible",
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          home: HomePage(),
          routes: {
            BookChapters.routeName: (ctx) => BookChapters(),
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
void main() async{ 
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await setTheme();
  runApp(Bible()); 
}
```

Just a side note, try using Dart features in your code

```
if (_prefs == null) _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

_prefs ??= await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

.

```
if (_prefs.containsKey('theme')) {
  _isDark = _prefs.getBool('theme') == true ? true : false;
} else {
  _isDark = false;
}

_isDark = _prefs.containKey('theme') ? _prefs.getBool('theme') : false;
```